# Не могу создать регулярку на С# для парса данных из JSON

Tags: c#, json, регулярные-выражения

```
"currencies":{
   "EUR":{
   "ask":"30.0000",
   "bid":"29.5000"
 },
   "RUB":{
   "ask":"0.3860",
   "bid":"0.3680"
 },
 "USD":{
   "ask":"26.7400",
   "bid":"26.5600"
 }
}
```

Нужно создать регулярку для получения данных Bid из USA.
Код моей регулярки

```
"USD":{"...":".*?","...":"(.*?)"
```

Не работает. Поможете с написанием ее ? В чем ошибка ?

Comment: Это вы должны сказать, какая у вас ошибка. Судя по всему, даже не компилируется? Символы кавычки в строковом литерале нужно экранировать: `\"`.

Comment: Возьмите json-парсер и не мучайтесь. Благо этих парсеров имеется несколько штук. Какой именно взять, зависит от платформы, под которую вы пишете. Укажите её и получите точный совет.

Comment: JSON формат ни кто руками не парсит, для этого существуют десятки библиотек, от банальной серриализации, до обычного конвертирования.

Comment: MatchCollection matchUSDBid = Regex.Matches(json, @"""USD"":{""..."":"".*?"",""..."":""(.*?)""}""");

Comment: _Регулярные_ выражения предназначены для разбора _регулярных_ грамматик. Грамматика json является _нерегулярной_. Поэтому откажитесь от регексов и юзайте парсер.

Comment: Подскажите, какой-то не сложный ) Я раньше не занимался парсингом

Comment: System.Text.Json или Newtonsoft.Json. Могу оформить ответ с примером разобра. С одним из них.

Comment: Было бы очень кстати, если бы был пример

Comment: Укажите платформу, которую вы используете. Обычный .NET Framework или .NET Core? И точную версию в любом случае.

Comment: .NET framework последнюю версию

Answer (score 1):

Одна из проблем разбора json регулярками состоит в том, что пробельные символы (в том числе переводы строки) могут наличествовать в любом количестве.
Проще всего полностью убрать их, опять же с помощью регулярки.
После чего можно легко распарсить.

```
string json = ...;
json = Regex.Replace(json, @"\s+", "");
var pattern = "\"USD\":{\"ask\":\".*?\",\"bid\":\"(.*?)\"}";
var match = Regex.Match(json, pattern);
var bid = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

---

Показанный вами код является невалидным JSON. Нужны по крайней мере ещё одни фигурные скобки. Допустим, они есть.

Вместо регулярок лучше применить какой-нибудь парсер JSON.

Например, популярную библиотеку [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). Устанавливаем её из nuget. Открываем пространство имён

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

Далее достаточно следующего минимального кода:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var bid = jObject["currencies"]["USD"]["bid"];
```

---

Если не хочется тянуть в проект лишнюю зависимость в виде библиотеки, то можно использовать родной сериализатор дотнета - класс [JavaScriptSerializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8). Для этого достаточно подключить сборку System.Web.Extensions.dll.
Открываем пространство имён

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

Далее код по сути такой же, как и выше. Но нужны приведения к типу словаря. Из-за этого код получается более громоздким.

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var jObject = (Dictionary<string, object>)jss.DeserializeObject(json);
var currencies = (Dictionary<string, object>)jObject["currencies"];
var usd = (Dictionary<string, object>)currencies["USD"];

var bid = usd["bid"];
```